# Qt Regular Expression Escape Sequence Problem

Tags: regex, qt

I'm struggling to get a regular expression implemented. I'm using Qt creator on an Ubuntu system. I tested my regex against an example number with a 3rd party tool. So I believe the problem is not with the expression.
My desired reg ex:

> /\b(9410 ?\d{18})\b/i

I am putting the regex string into a QString variable. Which results in an error:

> QString test = "/\b(9410 ?\d{18})\b/i";   unknown escape sequence '\d'

In an attempt to fix, I add an extra \ at the point of the error:

> QString test = "/\b(9410 ?\\d{18})\b/i";
>   qWarning() << test;

Debugger indicates (note the \\):

> /\b(9410 ?\\d{18})\b/i

I also tried a raw string:

> QString test = R"(/\b(9410 ?\d{18})\b/i)";
>   qWarning() << test;

Debugger shows all single \ replaced with \\.

> /\\b(9410 ?\\d{18})\\b/i

None of these attempts has resulted in a working reg ex. There is something fishy going on with the back slashes. Appreciate your thoughts. I must be missing something simple...

EDIT: Here is some simplified code. When I run this it returns "FALSE" indicating no match. I tested this regex and number at regex101.com. Works there. That's why I believe something is flawed in my implementation. Just can't put my finger on it.

```
QRegularExpression re;
QString test = R"(/\b(9410 ?\d{18})\b/i)";
re.setPattern(test);
if(re.match("9410811298370146293071").hasMatch())
{
    qWarning() << "TRUE";
}
else {
    qWarning() << "FALSE";
}
```

Comment: The last one should be working (syntactically). If you want to use backslashes in strings they should be escaped (or use raw strings). I believe you should tell us what are you expecting from this regexp and why you're thinking that it's not working.

Comment: Hi @montonero. That's what I thought as well. I added some code to enhance the question. Thanks!

Comment: Try to omit options from your regexp (opening and closing slashes), since there's no letters in your match is not necessary to use case-insensitive option. In case if you still need it use setPatternOptions.

Comment: Thanks @montonero. I cleaned up the regex to "9410 ?\d{18}" and it now matches.

Answer (score 1):

Cleaned up the regex and it now matches.

```
QRegularExpression re;
QString test = R"(9410 ?\d{18})";
re.setPattern(test);
if(re.match("9410811298370146293071").hasMatch())
{
    qWarning() << "TRUE";
}
else {
    qWarning() << "FALSE";
}
```